# C# Elements in Dimension

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to find out number of elements in provided dimension using C#:

```
int [][] arr = new int [3][];
int elements_dim0 = arr.GetLength(0); // Returns 3, which is the size of dimension. I want it to return the actual count of elements in provided dimension.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int [][]` is not a multidimensional array - its jagged array (i.e. it's array of arrays). If you want to get length of array at some index, you should use

```
arr[0].Length
```

But make sure that you have initialized array element before getting it's length (otherwise you will get NullReferenceException). E.g.:

```
arr[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
arr[1] = new int[] { 4, 5 };
```

You can also initialize jagged array with array initializer syntax:

```
int[][] arr = { new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5 }, new[] { 6 } };
```

Note that multidimensional arrays are defined as `int [,]`. And you can use `GetLowerBound(int dimension)` (usually it's zero) and `GetUpperBound(int dimension)` to get bounds of each array dimension. E.g. creating multidimensional array of size 2 x 4:

```
int[,] grid = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 } };
grid.GetUpperBound(0);  // 1
grid.GetUpperBound(1);  // 3
```

Further readings: [Jagged Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Multidimensional Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, just understood how dumb was my question)

Comment: @Src there is no dumb questions :)